# Policy Gradient with continuous action space

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, policy-gradients, ai

How to apply reinforce/policy-gradient algorithms for continuous action space. I have learnt that one of the advantages of policy gradients is , it is applicable for continuous action space. One way I can think of is discretizing the action space same as the way we do it for dqn. Should we follow the same method for policy -gradient algorithms also ? Or is there any other way this is done?

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend checking out this related question/answer: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/25212/75152
That answer contains a good description of how policy gradient can be applied to a continuous action space.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, i had a little difficulty understanding some parts, so what I want to confirm is, even in policy gradients for continuous actions we discretize them into discrete actions. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No that's not correct - there's no need to discretize the action space with policy gradient.  For discrete problems, the policy returns a vector of probabilities for each action.  But in continuous problems, the policy returns a _continuous_ distribution over the action space.

Comment: okay, thanks!! @zachdj

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is possible. It can be done in the following way:

We assume that the action distribution is guassian, i.e. that we need to learn the parameters $\theta$ of $\mathcal{N}(a|\mu_\theta,\sigma_\theta)$. Let's say that $\theta$ is given by the weights of a neural network, which we find by optimizing the objective
$$\max_\theta \mathbb{E}_{p_{\theta}}\left[ R(s,a)p_\theta(a|s)\right],$$
where $p_\theta(s,a) = \mathcal{N}(a|\mu_\theta, \sigma_\theta)$ and $R(s,a)$ is the cumulative discounted reward. The gradient is then per policy gradient theorem simply $\mathbb{E}_{p_{\theta}}\left[\nabla_\theta R(s,a) \log p_\theta(a|s) \right]$.

In practice, we design a neural network to output one $\mu$ per action dimension and $\sigma$ can either be learned or kept fixed. If learned, we interpret the output as $\log \sigma$, so it can take any value (e.g., become negative). To sample the action we use the outputs learned by our network.

See e.g. [T. P. Lillicrap, J. J. Hunt, A. Pritzel, N. Heess, T. Erez, Y. Tassa, D. Silver, and D. Wierstra. “Continuous control with deep reinforcement learning,”](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02971) International Conference on Learning Representations, 2016.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's really helpful. But I'm not sure what do you mean by en value? :'In practice we design a neural network to output one μ per action dimension and σ can either be learned or kept fixed. If learned, interpret the output as logσ, so it can take en value.'

Comment: It was an error. I fixed it.